# Check if array contains $_GET['id']

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, get

So I'm querying database, and it will return an array of id's.

```
$val = $db->prepare("SELECT x FROM xx WHERE x_id='$xx'");
$val->execute();
$res = $val->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0);
```

Then, I will separate the array with commas,

```
$x= join('', $res);
```

and echoing it would return `1,18,32`.

Then I want to check if `$_GET['id']` is one of these numbers

```
if($_GET['id] contains one of these){ // so here lies the problem, how do I check that it contains 1/18 or 32?
//continue...
}
else{
echo "You have no right to view this.";
}
```

But how?

Comment: if(in_array($_GET['id], $res))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `in_array(val, array)`.

```
if(in_array($_GET['id'], $res)) echo "Welcome";
else echo "You have no business here.";
```

ref: http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

Comment: Didn't even know of such function, and googling it isn't too easy when english isn't my native language. Thanks!